# DocumentApp causes App Script executed from Javascript client to 401

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

Currently attempting to execute a GAS from a Javascript client. The GAS script is as follows:

```
function findAndReplace() {
    var doc = DocumentApp.openById('ID_OMITTED');
}
```

This executes fine by pressing Play in the GAS editor, however when I try to execute from my Javascript client, I click authorise.

[image: Authorisation]

Then I receive a 401.

```
Error calling API: {
    "error": {
        "code": 401,
        "message": "ScriptError",
        "status": "UNAUTHENTICATED",
        "details": [{
            "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.apps.script.v1.ExecutionError",
            "errorMessage": "Authorization is required to perform that action.",
            "errorType": "ScriptError"
        }]
    }
}
```

And now when I press Play in the GAS editor, I get a `Action not allowed` error. I can then create a new script by copying it, press Play and it works fine. Executing the from the Javascript causes the whole the 401 and then the whole cycle repeats.

However if I execute a simple:

```
function test() {
    return 'hello';
}
```

It works, and returns

```
Folders under your root folder:
    h (0)
    e (1)
    l (2)
    l (3)
    o (4)
```

(The output looks like this because the program expects an array, as you can see below).

This is the Javascript client, basically copy and paste of the Javascript quickstart.

```
var CLIENT_ID = 'CLIENT_ID_OMITTED';
var SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'];

function checkAuth() {
    gapi.auth.authorize(
        {
            'client_id': CLIENT_ID,
            'scope': SCOPES.join(' '),
            'immediate': true
        }, handleAuthResult
    );
}

function handleAuthResult(authResult) {
    var authorizeDiv = document.getElementById('authorize-div');
    if (authResult && !authResult.error) {
        authorizeDiv.style.display = 'none';
        callScriptFunction();
    } else {
        authorizeDiv.style.display = 'inline';
    }
}

function handleAuthClick(event) {
    gapi.auth.authorize(
        {client_id: CLIENT_ID, scope: SCOPES, immediate: false},
        handleAuthResult
    );
    return false;
}

function callScriptFunction() {
    var scriptId = "SCRIPT_ID_OMITTED";

    var request = {
        'function': 'findAndReplace'
    };

    var op = gapi.client.request({
        'root': 'https://script.googleapis.com',
        'path': 'v1/scripts/' + scriptId + ':run',
        'method': 'POST',
        'body': request
    });

    op.execute(function(resp) {
        if (resp.error && resp.error.status) {
            appendPre('Error calling API:');
            appendPre(JSON.stringify(resp, null, 2));
        } else if (resp.error) {
            var error = resp.error.details[0];
            appendPre('Script error message: ' + error.errorMessage);

            if (error.scriptStackTraceElements) {
                appendPre('Script error stacktrace:');
                for (var i = 0; i < error.scriptStackTraceElements.length; i++)         {
                    var trace = error.scriptStackTraceElements[i];
                    appendPre('\t' + trace.function + ':' + trace.lineNumber);
                }
            }
        } else {
            var folderSet = resp.response.result;
            if (Object.keys(folderSet).length === 0) {
                appendPre('No folders returned!');
            } else {
                appendPre('Folders under your root folder:');
                Object.keys(folderSet).forEach(function(id){
                    appendPre('\t' + folderSet[id] + ' (' + id  + ')');
                });
            }
        }
    });
}

function appendPre(message) {
    var pre = document.getElementById('output');
    var textContent = document.createTextNode(message + '\n');
    pre.appendChild(textContent);
}
```

I made sure to create the permissions for `DocumentApp`, by copying it. Which when the copy is ran it gives me this prompt:

[image: Permission request]

Which I obviously accept.

I create a new project on the script each time, enabling the Scripts API

[image: Enabling API]

and then creating an OAuth2 client,

[image: Creating client id]

copying the client id into the script. I also `Deploy as API Executable` on the script, and take the script id.

What am I missing? Why is the code producing a 401? And why is the GAS script then mysteriously returning `Action now allowed` in the editor only to work once its copied?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying to do this for a couple nights I solved it straight after posted to SO... typical!

[This post solved it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36455612/2296182)

Basically, go to `File > Project Properties` and click the `Scopes` tab. From here you can see all the scopes required by your project.

This then must be added to the scopes array in your client-side javascript.

So my scopes now looks like this:

```
var SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/documents'];
```

Why the GAS script then decide to return `Action not allowed` I'll never know, it really threw me off the trail.

Hopefully this helps some body else.